# List actually used maven plugins in XML format for pom

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

It is an often helpful practice to declare the versions of all used maven plugins in the pom.xml, e.g. to make old builds reproducible after a new plugin version comes out. For a fresh project: is there a way to output the plugins currently used in the build in the XML-format I could easily put into the pluginManagement section of the pom.xml?

I found that [versions:display-plugin-updates](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/display-plugin-updates-mojo.html) does output the plugins with versions that are not yet fixed, and [help:effective-pom](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html) does display the actually used versions implicitly in `<build><plugins>`, but garbled with the configuration, executions and other information not needed for the pluginManagement section. So I'm looking for something easier - just like [mvn -DoutputXML=true dependency:analyze](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html) does for dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

How about parsing the output of `help:effective-pom` ?

With `grep` for a quick-and-dirty solution :

```
$ mvn help:effective-pom -Doutput=effective-pom.xml
$ grep "<plugin>" -A 3 effective-pom.xml
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.8</version>
    </plugin>
    [...]
```

Or with an XML Parser and the use of XSLT or XQuery for a more robust solution.

For example, the following XQuery code

```
declare default element namespace "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0";
string-join(
    for $plugin in //plugin
    return string-join(($plugin/groupId/text(), $plugin/artifactId/text(), $plugin/version/text()), ":"),
    "&#10;"
)
```

Will produce this kind of output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>maven-antrun-plugin:1.3
maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5
maven-dependency-plugin:2.8
maven-release-plugin:2.3.2
maven-source-plugin:3.0.1
maven-clean-plugin:2.5
maven-install-plugin:2.4
maven-deploy-plugin:2.7
maven-site-plugin:3.3
```

Note that the xml header could be removed with the appropriate configuration.